# How to remove rows of a file whose value in the second column appears a specific number of times?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file with rows of integers. I want to remove rows where the value in the second column does not appear in any other row's second column.

ex:

```
4 5 6 // row 0
1 2 3 // row 1
3 3 3 // row 2
4 5 4 // row 3
3 4 5 // row 4
2 2 4 // row 5
```

Column 2 has values 3 and 4 that only occur once out of all the rows. I want to remove rows that have these unique column 2 values, rows 2 and 4.

I need these sorted by column 2 also so what I currently have is

```
$ sort -k2 -n filename > filename_sorted
```

But I'm not sure how to identify the rows whose column 2 value is unique and remove them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just process the file twice: first to count the amount of times every 2nd column value appears and secondly to print those who appear more than once:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]++; next} a[$2]>1' file file
4 5 6 // row 0
1 2 3 // row 1
4 5 4 // row 3
2 2 4 // row 5
```

Comment: Define "nothing happens". Did you give the file as a parameter twice?

Comment: It doesn't produce an output. File was given as a parameter twice.

Comment: @Sasspedence I used the file as you showed in the question. If your file is different, please update your question with that input and the exact command you are using.

Comment: ugh, I had used a ) instead of }... I got it now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the filtering on any `awk`:

```
awk '
    {
        seen[$2]++ 
        line[$2]=$0
    }
END {
    for (i in seen)
        if (seen[i]==1)
            print line[i]
}' file
```

For filtering, if you happen to use `gawk 4x`, you can do this in one go by adding the following:

```
BEGIN {PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"}
```

Otherwise, the easiest is to pipe it to `sort`:

```
... | sort -nk2
```

Comment: this will do the inverse of what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `sort + awk`:

```
sort -k2 -n file | awk 'p == $2{if (r != "") print r; print; r=""} p != $2{p=$2; r=$0}'
1 2 3 // row 1
2 2 4 // row 5
4 5 4 // row 3
4 5 6 // row 0
```